# Pass values up through a tree in C

Tags: c, memory-management, tree

I'm writing a simple parser in C and I'm not sure which is the best way to pass results up my tree as it gets evaluated.

Here's my current code, the node struct and the walk function to evaluate the tree.

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    void* data;
    Symbol type;
} node;

void* walk(node* n) {
    if (n != NULL) {

        if (n->type == plus) {

            int x = 0;
            int a = *(int*)walk(n->left);
            int b = *(int*)walk(n->right);

            x = a + b;

            return &x;

        } else if (n->type == number) {
            return (int*)n->data;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

From the code you can see when I add two numbers together I'm storing the result in a local variable and returning the address to that variable, I know this is undefined behaviour, so I thought about using malloc and changing my code to this:

```
int* x = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
int a = *(int*)walk(n->left);
int b = *(int*)walk(n->right);

*x = a + b;

return x;
```

But the problem with this code is, I'm not sure what is the best way to free this memory I just malloc'd.

Should I walk the tree a second time and free all of the memory that way or is the a better way to free the memory when I'm done or is there a better way to propagate values through my tree?

Comment: why not just make walk return an int?

Comment: @Bwebb because I'd like the tree to return more than just numbers in future. I read you should use void* when you want to return values of different types.

Comment: If you have to return polymorphic data (`void*`, often disguised as opaque typeis how you do this in C) you will have to bite the bullet and provide complete set of APIs, including one to free up the memory, and require users to call that once they are done with the result.

Comment: why don't you add a new field to your `node` struct to hold a pointer to the value that you're passing up the tree.

Comment: Last time I wrote one of these (uni assignment last century) we passed a function pointer on the walk, and called it, passing `node->data`.  Sure this just moves the problem somewhere else, but it stops the tree-code being polluted with data-service functionality.  This function can then have a `static` accumulator, store to a global, `malloc()`ed buffer, whatever.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and interesting ideas I wouldn't have thought of!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to traverse the tree for second time. Notice that you do not need values of a and b after summing them into x. so you can free them after addition which is shown in @flu's answer. More over, you can do it without using extra memory for flag.

Note: this code will through runtime error for invalid input. to handle this errors check for NULL pointers before accessing a pointer.

```
void* walk(node* n) {
    if (n != NULL) {
        if (n->type == plus) {
            int * x = malloc(sizeof(int));
            int * a = (int*)walk(n->left);
            int * b = (int*)walk(n->right);
            *x = *a + *b;

            free(a);
            free(b);

            return x;
        } else if (n->type == number) {
            int * val = malloc(sizeof(int)); //allocate dynamic memory for the leaf node so that all nodes can be freed without checking.
            *val = n->data;
            return val;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra argument `needToFree` to inform the caller to free the returned pointer.

```
void* walk(node* n, bool* needToFree) {
    if (n != NULL) {
        if (n->type == plus) {
            bool needToFreeA;
            bool needToFreeB;
            int * x = malloc(sizeof(int));
            int * a = (int*)walk(n->left,  &needToFreeA);
            int * b = (int*)walk(n->right, &needToFreeB);
            *x = *a + *b;

            if( needToFreeA ) free(a);
            if( needToFreeB ) free(b);

            *needToFree = true;
            return x;
        } else if (n->type == number) {
            *needToFree = false;
            return (int*)n->data;
        }
    }
    *needToFree = false;
    return NULL;
}
```